# Installing gems, ruby on rails. Error with json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rubygems

I'm currently trying to create new app with rails, wanted to install gems in my app directory and got following message:

```
    root@ubuntup:/dev/movies-forum# bundle install --path vendor/bundle
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies....
Installing rake 12.3.0
Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Installing json 1.8.6 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.6/ext/json/ext/generator
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171125-3993-154eb9h.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/json-1.8.6/gem_make.out
Installing minitest 5.10.3
Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
Installing builder 3.2.3
Installing erubis 2.7.0
Installing mini_portile2 2.3.0
Installing crass 1.0.3
Installing rack 1.6.8
Installing mini_mime 1.0.0
Installing arel 6.0.4
Installing debug_inspector 0.0.3 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.3/ext/debug_inspector
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171125-3993-1n3hl3h.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/debug_inspector-0.0.3/gem_make.out
Using bundler 1.11.2
Installing byebug 9.1.0 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/byebug-9.1.0/ext/byebug
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171125-3993-g49k1z.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/byebug-9.1.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/byebug-9.1.0/gem_make.out
Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Installing execjs 2.7.0
Installing thor 0.20.0
Installing ffi 1.9.18 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18/ext/ffi_c
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171125-3993-yzalv6.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18 for inspection.
Results logged to /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.18/gem_make.out
Installing multi_json 1.12.2
Installing rb-fsevent 0.10.2
Installing rdoc 4.3.0
Installing tilt 2.0.8
Installing sqlite3 1.3.13 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/ext/sqlite3
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171125-3993-1y1q30j.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13 for inspection.
Results logged to /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.13/gem_make.out
Installing turbolinks-source 5.0.3
Installing i18n 0.9.1
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.6'` succeeds before bundling.
root@ubuntup:/dev/movies-forum# gem install json -v '1.8.6'
Fetching: json-1.8.6.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.6/ext/json/ext/generator
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171125-4056-c2r6jm.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/json-1.8.6/gem_make.out
root@ubuntup:/dev/movies-forum# which bundler
/usr/bin/bundler
root@ubuntup:/dev/movies-forum# gem install bundler && rbenv rehash
Fetching: bundler-1.16.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.16.0
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.16.0
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.16.0
Done installing documentation for bundler after 4 seconds
1 gem installed
Program rbenv nie jest obecnie zainstalowany. Możesz go zainstalować wpisując:
apt install rbenv
root@ubuntup:/dev/movies-forum# bundle install --path vendor/bundle
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies....
Using rake 12.3.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Installing json 1.8.6 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.6/ext/json/ext/generator
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171125-4146-njwwhh.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/json-1.8.6/gem_make.out
Using minitest 5.10.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
Using crass 1.0.3
Using rack 1.6.8
Using mini_mime 1.0.0
Using arel 6.0.4
Installing debug_inspector 0.0.3 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.3/ext/debug_inspector
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171125-4146-r39wqa.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/debug_inspector-0.0.3/gem_make.out
Using bundler 1.11.2
Installing byebug 9.1.0 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/byebug-9.1.0/ext/byebug
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171125-4146-16t55au.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/byebug-9.1.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/byebug-9.1.0/gem_make.out
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using thor 0.20.0
Installing ffi 1.9.18 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18/ext/ffi_c
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171125-4146-ngcier.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18 for inspection.
Results logged to /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.18/gem_make.out
Using multi_json 1.12.2
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.2
Using rdoc 4.3.0
Using tilt 2.0.8
Installing sqlite3 1.3.13 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/ext/sqlite3
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171125-4146-9yhg8k.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13 for inspection.
Results logged to /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.13/gem_make.out
Using turbolinks-source 5.0.3
Using i18n 0.9.1
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.6'` succeeds before bundling.
root@ubuntup:/dev/movies-forum# 
root@ubuntup:/dev/movies-forum# gem bundler install
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command bundler
root@ubuntup:/dev/movies-forum# sudo gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.16.0
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.16.0
Done installing documentation for bundler after 3 seconds
1 gem installed
root@ubuntup:/dev/movies-forum# bundle install --path vendor/bundle
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies....
Using rake 12.3.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Installing json 1.8.6 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.6/ext/json/ext/generator
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171125-4191-1krkby3.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/json-1.8.6/gem_make.out
Using minitest 5.10.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
Using crass 1.0.3
Using rack 1.6.8
Using mini_mime 1.0.0
Using arel 6.0.4
Installing debug_inspector 0.0.3 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.3/ext/debug_inspector
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171125-4191-3mbadh.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/debug_inspector-0.0.3/gem_make.out
Using bundler 1.11.2
Installing byebug 9.1.0 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/byebug-9.1.0/ext/byebug
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171125-4191-1ihoksu.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/byebug-9.1.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/byebug-9.1.0/gem_make.out
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using thor 0.20.0
Installing ffi 1.9.18 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18/ext/ffi_c
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171125-4191-ns9wm1.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18 for inspection.
Results logged to /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.18/gem_make.out
Using multi_json 1.12.2
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.2
Using rdoc 4.3.0
Using tilt 2.0.8
Installing sqlite3 1.3.13 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/ext/sqlite3
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171125-4191-1hupaig.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13 for inspection.
Results logged to /dev/movies-forum/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.13/gem_make.out
Using turbolinks-source 5.0.3
Using i18n 0.9.1
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.6'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Obviously what I did was:

```
root@ubuntup:/dev/movies-forum# gem install json -v '1.8.6'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.6/ext/json/ext/generator
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171125-4328-ttizdh.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/json-1.8.6/gem_make.out
```

What should I do with all these errors? I got a json-1.8.6 directory in .../gems. I see 24 other gems there but shouldn't the amount of it be around 70? I'm not really an expert in rails, it's my first try.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did and it helped:

```
apt-get install ruby-dev
```

When I was trying to host a server there was a problem with "uglifier" but this helped:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why installing `ruby-dev` would fix an issue with json 1.8.6...but it works! So thanks.